# IE Workaround? border-radius + background-color + border = bleeding background

Tags: css, internet-explorer

It seems something like this has been addressed before, but most of what I'm finding is for the more generic issue that doesn't pertain to most browsers today. I'm encountering the [known IE issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/3342037/) where using `border-radius` with a border and a background (a color in my case) results in the background *bleeding* beyond the border.

I'm wondering if there is a workaround that actually can mask this issue... Some of the things I've tried:

- `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />`
- `overflow:hidden` on the parent
- `background-clip:border-box`
- adding .1 to the `border-radius`

None of these have worked. Is there another workaround (other than "use images") while I wait for yon IE team to fix things?

I've created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrissigler/4o440k5b/) that illustrates this well and documents what I've found in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing from Zeev's answer, which moves the `background-color` to a `:before` or `:after` (which only substitutes a subpixel gap for a subpixel bleed, and across more browsers), and Phil's answer, which moves the `border` to an `:after` (which didn't really fix the problem).

Move the `background-color` to a `:before` as suggested by Zeev, but give it padding equal to the `border-width` minus two (or use `calc()`). Then give it negative `top` and `left` positioning with that same amount.

Then move the `border` to the `:after` but give it negative `top` and `left` positioning equal to the `border-width`.

This creates an oversized background and recenters it below the content. Then it creates an oversized border and centers it around the content. You could probably oversize the background to other degrees and get the same result. The point is to make it **bigger than the hole inside** the border, but **smaller than the outside** of the border. This, naturally, would fail with thin borders, though.

```css
body {
  background: white;
}
.bluebox {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.redcircle {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: black;
}
.redcircle::before,
.redcircle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.redcircle::before {
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  padding: 8px;
}
.redcircle::after {
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="bluebox">
  <div class="redcircle">
    !
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this before.

I recommend instead styling the border with CSS generated content, in a manner such as this:

```
.redcircle::after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:10px solid yellow;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events: none; //ensures no clicks propogate if this is desired
}
```

Comment: I did investigate further in IE, and I couldn't find a simple way around what appears to be a rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can crate an `::before` or `::after` **CSS Pseudo** and make your `background: red;` on them. Set your width, height and border-radius on 100% and for example don't change `z-index` to -1, you can see his get the inside width and hight and don't bleeding out.

---

[image]

- Screenshot from **Explorer 9** on **Vista**

---

**And now for example (how its look without z-index play):**

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.bluebox {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.redcircle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 140px;
  top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: black;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
}

.redcircle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bluebox">
  <div class="redcircle">
    !
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**And this one for using:**

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.bluebox {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.redcircle {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 140px;
  top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: black;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
}

.redcircle::before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bluebox">
  <div class="redcircle">
    !
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zeevkatz/z5903mm9/1/)**

Comment: This works well. It's not pretty, but it's not nearly as clunky as some other hacks I've had to employ for IE in the past. And if you cross your eyes, you can make semantic sense out of it. Thanks, Zeev.

Comment: after I started implementing, I'm saw that this only trades one problem for another. Now there's a seemingly *subpixel gap between the background and the border* rather than a *subpixel bleed beyond the border*. I think I've got a hacky workaround, though, and I'll post it shortly.

Comment: Can you screenshot that?

Comment: Sure. This is your snippet here, run on IE11: http://res.cloudinary.com/chrissigler/image/upload/v1477580313/zeevs_snip_gap_gvigqi.png

It's easy to miss on the white side, but look on the blue side.

Comment: You can uglier it and add calc(100% + 1px) to the width and height, but is your choice...

Comment: Look at this demo https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/yd09xab9/. Its work fine.

Comment: And one more thing, you try to use `box-shadow`? Something like this `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px yellow;`?

Answer (score 0):

background-clip fixes this issue:

```
.bluebox {   
   background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please explain your code and how this code solves the problem. also, you can use snippet/fiddle to share the code.